# XAML TextBlock XML: StringFormat to display number

Tags: xml, xaml, string-formatting, textblock

My XML data is:

```
<Num>12.6</Num>
```

I bind this to a XAML TextBlock and want to display the value as a rounded number without decimal point. So this value should be displayed as 13. Similarly, 12.2 should be displayed as 12, etc.

I need code in the StringFormat below (at the ...) to do what I want:

```
<TextBlock Text= "{Binding Num, StringFormat=...}" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a converter:

```
public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.Parse(value as string);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in xaml, declare the converter:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:StringToDoubleConverter x:Key="StringToDoubleConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And finally use it in the binding, together with the StringFormat:

```
<TextBlock Text= "{Binding Num, StringFormat=n0, Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}}" />
```

The zero in `n0` indicates no decimal places ([Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx))

Comment: It still displays the string exactly with decimal point and without rounding. Must I do any kind of conversion? I suspect the value is currently treated as a string. I might need to specify that it's a number somehow. Thanks.

Comment: That's weird. It works for me flawlessly being Num a double. Try using n2 instead of n0 to see if it shows 2 decimal places. Also, what is the type of Num?

Comment: I don't specify the type of Num other than that it's displayed in a TextBlock. Does this imply that it's of type string? That's why I wonder about the conversion.

Comment: You don't need to specify the type. It's automatically detected by the binding. This will work only if Num is a double, decimal or float.

Comment: So how and where do I specify that Num is double, decimal or float? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were using xml :) You will need to use a converter to parse the value, and then use the StringFormat. I just added an example. Hope it helps!